# Cannot find package java.nio.file

Tags: java, nio

My java compiler cannot find the `java.nio.file` package. Consider:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    }
}
```

compiling with

```
bash$ javac Test.java
```

gives

```
Test.java:1: package java.nio.file does not exist
import java.nio.file.*;
                ^
Test.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Path
location: class Test
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    ^
Test.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Paths
location: class Test
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
                               ^
3 errors
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and I think I have JDK 7 installed (see: [package java.nio.file does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577797/package-java-nio-file-does-not-exist) )

```
bash$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What do you see if you type `javac -version` ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338586/how-to-import-java-nio-file-package

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is entirely possible that you have `java` 1.7, but `javac` 1.6 or even 1.5

maybe you can use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

to configure it. If you cannot choose 1.7, then you need to upgrade your JDK package.

Comment: Yes you are right.. I have for some reason javac version 1.6.. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/117189/apt-get-install-openjdk-7-jdk-doesnt-install-javac-why .. It works if I write `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac Test.java` instead of `javac Test.java` ..

Comment: From the second answer (which should have been the accepted one): The proper Debian/Ubuntu way to configure which javac is pointed to by /usr/bin/javac is to use the update-alternatives command.

Comment: I have java 8 installed in window's and when I compiled test.java gave error `test.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        private static void getAllFilse(File curDir) {
                                        ^
  symbol:   class File
  location: class test`

Answer (score 7):

Java NIO was introduced in Java 7. Compilers from earlier versions of the JDK will baulk at any code that contains these NIO classes. You need to upgrade to JDK 7.

Answer (score 4):

I would check

```
javac -version
```

as you might not have Java 7 JDK installed correctly and so only `java` has been, possibly one the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've passed the correct address for `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` which is Java 7 installation directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I use Eclipse. There is an option to set JDK Compliance. I set from 1.5 to 1.8 and recompiled the projects. It is fine now. I suggest to set globally and disable this option on project level.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if your have the "sourceCompatility" inside your builde.gradle file, example:

```
sourceCompatibility = 'your_jdk_version'
```

And check if your: File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle

Has the Gradle JVM to the selected version.