# How to use Jerseys @Path AND java.nio.file.Path?

Tags: java, jersey

I am working on a jersey service. When I import `java.nio.file` then I get a problem with the `@Path` annotation and the Path interface in NIO.

The error is "type ambiguous", what makes sense to me. 
But I do not know how to resolve it.

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import java.nio.file.*;   // problem with @PATH

@Path ("service")
public class Service 
{ 
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        public String getIt () 
        {
            return "blabla";
        }
}
```

I am not an expert with annotations and need a little help here. Thanks!

Comment: Does not help - I need java.nio.file.Path :-)

Comment: Do you have different java versions installed and accidentally mixed them? If so, then maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20029301/9818506

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fully qualified class names to avoid the conflict. For example, replace `@Path` with `@javax.ws.rs.Path` and `Path` with `java.nio.file.Path`.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware I can do that with annotations.

Comment: Glad to help. :)